# Deserialize complex json body, validate one element in it, then through that, map to another element (JAVA) is it possible?

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization

I have a json array to work with, like so:

```
[
    {
        "id": "12345",
        "eauthId": "123451234512345123451234512345",
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "middieInitial": "M",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "email": "janedoe@usda.gov",
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": "CTIS_ROLE_ID",
                "name": "A test role for CTIS",
                "treatmentName": "Fumigation"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "67890",
        "eauthId": "678906789067890678906789067890",
        "firstName": "John",
        "middieInitial": "Q",
        "lastName": "Admin",
        "email": "johnadmin@usda.gov",
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": "CTIS_ADMIN",
                "name": "An admin role for CTIS",
                "treatmentName": "System Administration"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My task is to find out the user's "roles" --> "name", once match, get that user's email address and sign in using that email address. It seems like a simple task, but it has been really kicking my bottom, since  digging into API is new to me. I've tried different libraries (Jackson, RestAssured, Json Simple) and finally GSon. I don't have time to sit and study everything from the scratch. I just needed a quick solution. But it definitely hasn't been quick. Is anyone kind enough to help me out with this. I'd really appreciate it.

```
closeableHttpResponse = restClient.get(ConfigurationReader.get("base_url") + ConfigurationReader.get("user_endpoint"));
//Status code
int statusCode = closeableHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
System.out.println("statusCode = " + statusCode);
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(closeableHttpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
Type userListType = new TypeToken<List<Users>>(){}.getType(); 
List<Users> users = (List<Users>) new Gson().fromJson(responseString, userListType); 
Roles roles = new Gson().fromJson(responseString, Roles.class);
```

it gives me this error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is

```
Type userListType = new TypeToken<List>(){}.getType();
List users = (List) new Gson().fromJson(responseString, userListType);
```

You are not receiving just a list, you are actually deserializing an array of lists.

So try this:

```
List[] users = (List[]) new Gson().fromJson(responseString, List[].class);
```